# Python IndexError in my Nearest Neighbour Algorithm for TSP

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman, index-error

I am trying to solve TSP using the nearest algorithm, but I got stuck at the IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 38. For my algorithm I'm using a distance matrix 38x38 that was transformed from .tsp format.

```
import numpy as np
import tsplib95
import networkx

# load the tsplib problem
problem = tsplib95.load('dj38.tsp')

# convert into a networkx.Graph
graph = problem.get_graph()

# convert into a numpy distance matrix
distance_matrix = networkx.to_numpy_matrix(graph)



def NN(A, start):
    """Nearest neighbor algorithm.
    A is an NxN array indicating distance between N locations
    start is the index of the starting location
    Returns the path and cost of the found solution
    """
    path = [start]
    cost = 0
    n = A.shape[0]
    mask = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)  # boolean values indicating which locations have not been visited
    mask[start] = False

    for i in range(n-1):
        last = path[-1]
        next_ind = np.argmin(A[last][mask]) # find minimum of remaining locations
        next_loc = np.arange(n)[mask][next_ind] # convert to original location
        path.append(next_loc)
        mask[next_loc] = False
        cost += A[last, next_loc]

    return path, cost

#print(distance_matrix)

#print(distance_matrix.shape)

print(NN(distance_matrix,1))
```

the distance matrix is 38x38 and looks like this

```
[[   0.  291.  794. ... 1852. 1625. 1858.]
 [ 291.    0.  513. ... 1599. 1413. 1649.]
 [ 794.  513.    0. ... 1331. 1288. 1514.]
 ...
 [1852. 1599. 1331. ...    0.  441.  444.]
 [1625. 1413. 1288. ...  441.    0.  236.]
 [1858. 1649. 1514. ...  444.  236.    0.]]
```

and the error I'm getting is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Irina/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(NN(distance_matrix,1))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Irina/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 36, in NN
    next_ind = np.argmin(A[last][mask]) # find minimum of remaining locations
                         ~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Irina/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 193, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 38
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't get an error when I run this with a randomly generated matrix! (`np.random.random((38,38))`)

Python 3.10 and numpy 1.24.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks. But what is wrong with my matrix?

Comment: I can't say that unless I can see the whole data generation process and be able to debug it. I would recommend using a debugger to narrow down the source of the error.